# Using Theme Dialog Layout and XML Strings

Tags: android, xml, string, layout, themes

I have a layout, `main.xml`.  When you click the button `describeButton`, it opens a new theme.dialog layout called `checklist.xml`.  On `checklist.xml`, users are given a series of check boxes they can use to describe a picture.  After they check as many check boxes as they please, they can click the `okButton` to go back to the `main.xml` layout.

So here are my questions:

- How do I take the check boxes that users selected, turn the selections into a string, and store it as a string in the `strings.xml` file?
- How do I code the `okButton` on `checklist.xml` to close the layout, which in turn will return the users to `main.xml`?

Thank you for your help.

**Edit**
Here's the code I'm using at the moment:

```
public class Descriptor extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.checklist);

        final CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);



        Button selOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectOK);
        selOK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
                     // add a string to an existing string in strings.xml
                 }
                 // repeat this if statement for all checkboxes

                 // execute something to close this layout
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about `res/values/strings.xml`? After you compile an APK you cannot change the XML files. During compilation the XML files are used to generate an R.java file which is a java implementation of your XML files. These files are actual java source that you can't change or alter.

One way to achieve what I think you are trying to do is to attach a listener to the checkboxes and then keep track of when a user checks or un-checks a box. Here is an example of a dialog with radio buttons from the [Android Docs for Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). It should be pretty simple to convert to checkboxes by using `builder.setMultiChoiceItems` instead of `builder.setSingleChoiceItems`.  In fact here is a [link to the multiChoiceItems method doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setMultiChoiceItems%28android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener%29).

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

With regards to your second question, your OkButton can just close the dialog. In your main activity can setup an array of booleans with one boolean for every string you are going to display. Then in your the `onClick` method can change the individual boolean values based upon which checkboxes are checked.   Then when the dialog closes you can examine the array of booleans to see what checkboxes the users checked.

Comment: Yes, I mean `res/values/strings.xml`.  And oh, I didn't know you couldn't alter the XML after execution.  With the code you provided above - where is the string stored?  Also, can users select more than one color in your example?  Can they de-select a color and as a result have that removed from the output string?

Comment: @MikeGates see my recent update about MultiChoice vs SingleChoice

Comment: That's great! Thanks! That answers my first question.  Do you have a solution to my 2nd question (I would assume it would be simple)?

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I will try this.  If all else fails, do you know how to close a layout, in case I end up using a layout instead of an AlertDialog?

Comment: By Layout do you mean Activity? you can close an activity with a call to finish()